# SwiftUI toggle switches

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I'm trying to implement a simple toggle switch but I'm having trouble saving the new toggle/switch status as when I change views and go back into the setting, it's defaulted back to the off switch. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
struct StudyMode: View {
      @State private var overdueFirst = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Overdue First")
      @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

      var body: some View {
        VStack {
          HStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $overdueFirst) {
              Text("Overdue cards first")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
              var newSwitch = false

              if self.overdueFirst == false {
                newSwitch = true
              }

              UserDefaults.standard.set(newSwitch, forKey: "Overdue First")
            }
          }

          Spacer()
          Text("By enabling this option, the cards will be ordered such that you will revise all overdue cards before you start learning new words.")
            .font(.system(size: 12))
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: try loading the value from user defaults in `onAppear()` and debug to see whats happening. Aso `onTapGuesture` can be reduced to `self.overdueFirst.toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `.onTapGesture` over `Toggle` is not called, because latter does not allow it (handling tap by itself, and even `.simultaneousGesture` will not help)

Here is possible approach to achieve the goal (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
...
// define proxy binding, wrapping direct work with UserDefaults
private let overdueFirst = Binding<Bool>(
    get: { UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Overdue First") },
    set: { UserDefaults.standard.set($0, forKey: "Overdue First") })

var body: some View {
  VStack {
    HStack {
      Toggle(isOn: overdueFirst) { // use proxy binding directly
        Text("Overdue cards first")
      }
    }
    ...
```

However I would recommend to bind this Toggle directly with your `UserSettings` corresponding property and handle sync with `UserDefaults` there (eg. on `didSet`).

Comment: Thanks, this code works. Do you mind elaborating on your last paragraph?