# How to execute non-view code inside a SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, viewbuilder

I have been struggling with this over and over again, so I think I'm missing something.  I need to do math, make a setting, assign a value or any of a host of simple operations in reaction to some user action, such as the example shown here, and SwiftUI is wanting a View where I don't need a view. There's got to be a way around the ViewBuilder's rules. I kind of worked around this by creating an unnecessary view and executing the code I need inside the View's init(), but that seems terribly awkward.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var showStuff = false

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Toggle(isOn: $showStuff)
            {
                Text("Label")
            }
            if showStuff
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Something")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this now is using **onChange(of:perform:)** modifier, for iOS14.0+

These simple executions (like do math, assign a value) are nothing but **actions** in swift terminology, which should be performed after touching any UI element because swiftUI is declarative. In your case, you can use this with any View type. Other similar options are **.onAppear()** or **.onDisappear()** (self-explanatory).

Surprisingly, apple documentation for these are actually good and elaborate.

Link - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)

Answer (score 17):

## Way 1 (best):

```
struct ExecuteCode : View {
    init( _ codeToExec: () -> () ) {
        codeToExec()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

usage:

```
HStack {
    ExecuteCode { 
        print("SomeView1 was re-drawn!")
        print("second print")
    }

    SomeView1()
}
```

## Way 2:

( my first way is better - you're able to write only simple code here )

```
HStack {
    // `let _ =` works inside of View!
    let _ = print("SomeView1 was re-drawn!") 

    SomeView1()
}
```

## Way 3:

( +- the same situation as in first way. Good enough solution. )

```
HStack {
    let _ = { // look here. "let _ =" is required
        print("SomeView1 was re-drawn!")
        print("second print")
    }() // look here. "()" is also required
    
    SomeView1()
}
```

Comment: Works Perfectly in SwiftUI with synchronous execution

Answer (score 4):

Views are actually so-called **Function Builders**, and the contents of the view body are used as arguments to to the `buildBlock` function, as mentioned by @Asperi.

An alternative solution if you must run code inside this context is using a closure that returns the desired view:

```
VStack {
    // ... some views ...
    { () -> Text in
      // ... any code ...
      return Text("some view") }()
    // ... some views ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI 2.0, there's a new ViewModifier [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview/onchange(of:perform:)), that allows you to react to changes in values.

But you can create something similar to that with a neat trick (I forgot where I saw it, so unfortunately I can't leave proper attribution), by extending a `Binding` with `onChange` method:

```
extension Binding {
   func onChange(perform action: @escaping (Value, Value) -> Void) -> Self {
      .init(
         get: { self.wrappedValue },
         set: { newValue in
            let oldValue = self.wrappedValue
            DispatchQueue.main.async { action(newValue, oldValue) }
            self.wrappedValue = newValue
         })
   }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
Toggle(isOn: $showStuff.onChange(perform: { (new, old) in
  if new {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Something")
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you try to do, because actually every view block inside `body` is a `ViewBuidler.buildBlock` function arguments. Ie. you are in function *arguments space*. I hope you would not expect that expression like

`foo(Toggle(), if showStuff { ... } )`

would work (assuming `foo` is `func foo(args: View...)`. But this is what you try to do in `body`.

So expressions in SwiftUI have to be *out of ViewBuilder* block (with some exceptions which ViewBuilder itself supports for views).

Here is a solution for your case:

**SwiftUI 2.0**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("Something") var showStuff = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $showStuff) {
                Text("Label")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SwiftUI 1.0**

Find in already solved [SwiftUI toggle switches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507197/12299030)

*Note: `View.body` (excluding some action modifiers) is equivalent of `UIView.draw(_ rect:)`... you don't store UserDefaults in draw(_ rect:), do you?*